# Dont understand what is going on in this weird Java code syntax. I was told this is called passing a template type to a static method

Tags: java

I came across some piece of code in my organization that I don't even know how to begin

understanding. Could someone shed some light on what the code in class A is doing in java?

is doing and why its called passing a template type to a static method?

Class A:

```
 List<SearchIndexResponse> indexResponseList = ConnectionHelper

.<List<SearchIndexResponse>> tryExecute(new Callable<List<SearchIndexResponse>>()
```

Class B:

```
public class ConnectionHelper<T>
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
    .getLogger(ConnectionHelper.class);

    private static final int    CONNECTION_RETRIES = 3;

    private static final int    MIN_TIMEOUT        = 100;

    public static <T> T tryExecute(Callable<T> command)
    {
        T returnValue = null;
        long delay = 0;

        for (int retry = 0; retry < CONNECTION_RETRIES; retry++)
        {
            try ....
```

Comment: I know its a generic type. But what the heck is the period doing there to invoke a method on a generic angle bracket syntax? What tha..

Comment: I think in Class a it should be
    ConnectionHelper<List<SearchIndexResponse>>.tryExecute

Comment: Read up on [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).